# How to know when TAB key has been pressed in UWP (in tablet)?

Tags: c#, uwp, keyboard, key

I want to know when the user presses the **tab** key on their windows 10 tablet so that I can catch that and do some action in my **uwp app**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVE!!!!!

I try this

```
private void txt_Nombre_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Tab)
   {
       //Action do it
   }
}
```

With the event KeyDown

Comment: You should update your title, this code that you have mentioned will tell you the key that is pressed but will not trigger any keypress automatically.